# SWT layout and paint

Tags: java, swt

I have few questions about layout and paint procedures in SWT.

Fox example, I have a Composite with children. When I invoke composite.layout() what does it mean? Layout? Paint? I find confusing this phrase in the javadoc:

```
Note: Layout is different from painting. If a child is moved or resized such that an area in the parent is exposed, then the parent will paint. If no child is affected, the parent will not paint.
```

Another question is, what is going on when I set composite.setLayoutDeferred(true) and invoke after that composite.layout?

Also, what happens when I set composite.setRedraw(false) and after that invoke still the same composite.layout()?

I spent half of my day reading javadoc and doing some practice investigation, but it didn't shed any light on this problem. I can't understand the theory behind this API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let me try to explain this:

There are two types of `Widget`s involved here: Those that can have a layout (`Composite`s and its subclasses) and the other `Control`s.

When a `Paint` event occurs, a `Composite` (if it has a `Layout`) will cause it's children to repaint. If the children are `Composite`s as well, they will propagate this. If they are other `Control`s, they will repaint.

Repainting of a `Control` means that the "state" of this control has changed, i.e. in order to represent its stage properly, it has to do something. This can be caused by a resize event, or by hovering the mouse over it or by clicking on it, basically everything where the visual appearance has to change.

---

`Control#setRedraw(boolean)` does exactly what the JavaDoc says:

> If the argument is false, causes subsequent drawing operations in the receiver to be ignored. **No drawing of any kind can occur in the receiver until the flag is set to true.**

The difference to `Composite#setLayoutDeferred(boolean)` is, that events that occur while it was set to `false` will be cached and they will be performed, when it is set to `true` again.

---

If you call `.layout()` *after* you call those methods with `true`, nothing will happen, if you call them before, the event will take place.

Comment: Does this mean that Control#setRedraw(boolean) and Composite#setLayoutDeferred(boolean) generally have no differences, except caching you mentioned? I thought that layouting controls in Composite is independent from painting this controls. I still don't get why one method is named "setRedraw" and other "setLayoutDeferred" if they do the same thing.

Comment: @Steve Why don't you have a look at the source of [`Control`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.java.htm) and [`Composite`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite.java.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

Invoking `composite.layout()` means to let the set layout manager set the child controls position. Use this if you have changed some properties of the child controls or the configured layout which will influence the layout positions (heavily depends on the layout manager).

Use

```
control.setRedraw(false);
// other code
control.setRedraw(true);
```

to improve performance if `// other code` performs a lot of GUI modifications which would trigger a lot of smaller repaints.